# Wiping Android Emulator Without Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting this error

Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/edengrowney/StudioProjects/all_angles/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 arm64.

and it is fixed if I wipe data from Android studio, but Android Studio runs slow on my computer so I am using VS code, is there a way to wipe emulator without Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to delete the emulator and make a new one.  Or to edit that emulator and increase its amount of storage (emulator needs to be off to do that).